# Cannot call external js function unless put it in html file

Tags: javascript

I have trouble to call external javascript function.
In my HTML:

```
 <p>  <a id="delete" href="/some/url/">Delete</a> </p>
```

I want to confirm before deletion. If I put the code in the html file, it works:

```
 <script>
var test = document.getElementById("delete");
test.onclick = function popup(){return confirm("Are you sure?")};
</script>
```

However, if I put popup() function in external js file and include using "src=/path/to/external.js", the function cannot find, and no pop up window anymore.

I am pretty sure I type the correct path of external js, because I can open the js file in the html page source code. Also, if I use jquery.js file locally, it will not work, but if I use the jquery.js served by google CDN, it works. I am totally lost. Why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure that when your JS is executed, the `#delete` element does exist in DOM.

To do so, you could simply include the **.js** file before `</body>`.

If you'd like to include it before `</head>`, your should fire the event binding after DOM ready (on `DOMContentLoaded` event, or later, `window.onload`), because JS is executed once it's downloaded, and at that time `<body>` is not rendered yet, `document.getElementById("delete")` would be `null`.

---

If you want to separate the event listener, you could try following code:

```
function popup(){return confirm("Are you sure?")}
test.onclick = popup; // Attention! Without brackets here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the HTML element may not be on the page when the code is executed.
Use below:

```
window.onload=function(){
  var test = document.getElementById("delete");
  test.onclick = function popup(){return confirm("Are you sure?")};
};
```

Comment: But If I move the popup() function into external.js file and replaced the last line as: test.onclick = popup();  then it will not work. The popup function is not recognized.

Comment: @ohmygoddess then you need `test.onclick = popup`, without the brackets.

Comment: @Leo : That's it!  Thank you! Why in this case, I need call the function without brackets?   Only when the function takes parameters, then we can include "()"?

Comment: @ohmygoddess with brackets, it means call the function, and assign the function's **return value** to `test.onclick`. What you really want is to assign a **function** (event listener) to `test.onclick`, which will be executed when a mouse click occurs.

Comment: Got you! I undertand now. Thank you!